# What replaces cellpadding, cellspacing, valign, and align in HTML5 tables?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio, css-tables

In **Visual Studio**, I'm seeing these warnings:

> - Validation (HTML 5): Attribute 'cellpadding' is not a valid attribute of element 'table'.
> - Validation (HTML 5): Attribute 'cellspacing' is not a valid attribute of element 'table'.
> - Validation (HTML 5): Attribute 'valign' is not a valid attribute of element 'td'.
> - Validation (HTML 5): Attribute 'align' is not a valid attribute of element 'td'.

If they are not valid attributes in **HTML5**, what replaces them in CSS?

Comment: I've found that even with HTML5, the cellpadding and cellspacing attributes are still required.  That is to say, without explicitly declaring those attributes, the default padding and spacing are applied.  Therefore, I find that I must always set them to the value of "0" in order to nullify the default values.  It's possible that they've been deprecated but browsers have not yet picked up on them.  The default values are still applied in Chrome version 37.

Answer (score 543, accepted):

```
/* cellpadding */
th, td { padding: 5px; }

/* cellspacing */
table { border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 5px; } /* cellspacing="5" */
table { border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; }   /* cellspacing="0" */

/* valign */
th, td { vertical-align: top; }

/* align (center) */
table { margin: 0 auto; }
```

Comment: Its worth noting that border-spacing only seems to work when using this property on the table too "border-collapse:separate;"

Comment: @Samir -- Seems that a `float:right;` will do the trick. http://jsfiddle.net/HGFH7/

Answer (score 71):

This should solve your problem:

```
td {
    /* <http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/text-align>
     * left, right, center, justify, inherit
     */
    text-align: center;
    /* <http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/vertical-align>
     * baseline, sub, super, top, text-top, middle,
     * bottom, text-bottom, length, or a value in percentage
     */
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: FYI: moved from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367387/are-there-css-alternatives-to-the-deprecated-html-attributes-align-and-valign

Answer (score 17):

On particular table

```html
<table style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 10px;" >
    <tr>
      <td>Hi</td>
      <td>Hello</td>
    <tr/>
    <tr>
      <td>Hola</td>
      <td>Oi!</td>
    <tr/>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, can use for particular table

```
 <table style="width:1000px; height:100px;">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="top">Text</td> //Remove it
        <td class="tableFormatter">Text></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Add this css in external file

```
.tableFormatter
{
width:100%;
vertical-align:top;
text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: FYI: moved from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367387/are-there-css-alternatives-to-the-deprecated-html-attributes-align-and-valign

Comment: inline css not recommended.

Comment: Yes you are right. i do not recommending. We go for external css file .ClassName{ width: 100%; text-align: center; vertical-align:top;}
Thanks