# How can I code cellspacing=0 so it is valid HTML5?

Tags: html, css

I have HTML looking like this:

```
<table class="table" style="clear: both;" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
```

My IDE is telling me that width and cellspacing are not valid HTML5.

Is there a way I can code this so that it is valid?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, use the `border-collapse: collapse;` CSS rule (which has the same effect: no space between table cells). Note that this may not work in older browsers like IE 5 or 6, so if you need to support them you are out of luck.

```
<table class="table" style="clear: both; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;">
```

Answer (score 5):

The `width` and `cellspacing` attributes are indeed depreciated as of HTML5.  The proper way to handle this is with CSS.

For cellspacing, please see this answer: [In HTML5, with respect to tables, what replaces cellpadding, cellspacing, valign, and align?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048913/in-html5-with-respect-to-tables-what-replaces-cellpadding-cellspacing-valign)

I have excerpted the code from the answer in the link above (credit goes to @Drudge):

This is an example for cellspacing="5"

```
.table { 
    border-collapse:separate;
    border-spacing: 5px;
}
```

This is an example for cellspacing="0"

```
.table { 
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing: 0; 
}
```

To solve your `width` attribute not being valid, simply use the CSS `width` property:

```
.table {
    width:100%;
}
```