# Putting multi-iteration into div class HTML5

Tags: html

As I recall, the following iteration schemes produce a matrix. In my case a 5x5

```
  SCRIPT Language="JavaScript">
  document.write('<table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5">')
  for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  document.write('<tr>')
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++){
       document.write('<td>row ' + i + ', column ' + j + '</td>')
    }
    document.write('</tr>')
 }

 document.write('</table>')

 //-->
 </SCRIPT>
```

How would I wrap this in a div class that is set up with a margin and background color?

Comment: Do you want the `div` as part of the script? Are you wanting to instert the contents into an exisig `div`? What have you tried to date and what went wrong?

Comment: DigitalFront has it figured out. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
<SCRIPT Language="JavaScript">
  document.write('<div style="margin: 10px; background-color: blue;"><table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5">')
  for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
  document.write('<tr>')
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++){
       document.write('<td>row ' + i + ', column ' + j + '</td>')
    }
    document.write('</tr>')
 }

 document.write('</table></div>')

 //-->
 </SCRIPT>
```

Comment: It is interesting that as we increase the margin the background color adjusts.

Comment: @user2948897 perhaps you want padding, not margin?

Answer (score 0):

if you *have* to use document.write, and just want to wrap your table in a div, this would do it.

```
document.write('<div class="myclass" style="margin:5px; background-color:#000;">');
document.write('<table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="5">');
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    document.write('<tr>');
    for (j = 0; j < 5; j++){
       document.write('<td>row ' + i + ', column ' + j + '</td>');
    }
    document.write('</tr>');
}
document.write('</table>');
document.write('</div>');
```

this wraps it and puts style to it, but I could have misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do it that way, I'd go something like:

```
<div id="divWithTable" class="someClassName"></div>

<SCRIPT Language="JavaScript">
   var ourDiv = document.getElementById("divWithTable");
   var tableHTML = "<table>" 

   for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
     tableHTML += "<tr>";

     for (j = 0; j < 5; j++){
        tableHTML += "<td>row " + i + ", column " + j + "</td>"
     }

     tableHTML += "</tr>";  
    }

  tableHTML +="</table>";

  ourDiv.innerHTML = tableHTML;

//-->
</SCRIPT>
```

For your CSS use

```
.someClassName
{
    background-color:#F00;
    margin: 0.5em;
}

 // cellpadding
.someClassName table th, .someClassName table td { padding: 5px; }

// cellspacing
.someClassName table { border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 5px; }
```

This way you keep style seperate and only update the DOM once

As you have labled your question HTML5 note that many table attributes are [no longer part of the HTML5 spec and shouldn't be used](http://webdesign.about.com/od/tables/a/aa121597.htm). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048913/in-html5-with-respect-to-tables-what-replaces-cellpadding-cellspacing-valign) for more info.

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/tbH8y/.