# How to remove the default table border/spacing/padding?

Tags: html, css

I'm using a table to display an image, title and date. 
Everything is working great and I'm happy with how it looks, but around the image is some space I think it is the table border/margin/padding.

**I want to have the image against the left of the table, so no more blue between it.**

HTML:

```
<table style="background-color: blue;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="http://revistasindromes.com/images/100x100.gif"></td>
      <td>Hello world!</td>
      <td>Hello world!</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/VyflDYKYqxbTIYDBGQf4?p=preview) is a demo.

Comment: Could we possibly have a jsFiddle?

Comment: add attribute to the table tag cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"

Comment: @MuhammadSohailArif Sorry I kinda failed, I already prepared a demo but forgot to add it in the question.

Comment: This has to be a duplicate...

Comment: @staypuftman That's what I thought, but I couldn't find anything similar to this that solved my problem.

Comment: @DanMan not really, none of their answers solves the problem I had. While the answers to this question worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make your code as below:

```
<table style="background-color: blue;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This worked great! `<table style="background-color: blue;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">`

Comment: @Goldenowner great!!! :)

Comment: If you chose to adopt this, then do take note that both cellspacing and cellpadding on table element are both entirely obsolete, and as such their usage should be avoided.

Answer (score 3):

The [W3C Working Draft 08 October 2015 for HTML 5.1](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/Overview.html#contents) lists both `cellspacing` and `cellpadding` on `table` elements as obsolete, and as such its usage should be avoided.

Under section [11.2 Non-conforming features](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/obsolete.html#non-conforming-features) you'll find the following note;

> Elements in the following list are entirely obsolete, and must not be
>   used by authors

With both `cellpadding` and `cellspacing` added to the list

> - cellpadding on [table](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/semantics.html#the-table-element) elements
> - cellspacing on [table](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/semantics.html#the-table-element) elements

So here's your options;

**Option 1**

You can add the following styles to your current stylesheet;

```
table { 
  background-color: blue; 
  border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; /* cellspacing */
}

th, td { 
  padding: 0px;  /* cellpadding */
}
```

This solution will look something like this fiddle; https://jsfiddle.net/z9tz4Lcb/

**Option 2**

Normalize your CSS as mentioned by [Vucko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1763929/vucko) in the comments.

You'll either download and bundle the [normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/master/normalize.css) file directly from GitHub, or use some sort of CDN as seen below

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.3/normalize.min.css">
```

This solution will look something like this fiddle; https://jsfiddle.net/x7a6kjvo/

**.. and while you're at it**

You should also set `display: block;` in the page stylesheet for your `<img>`  tag to remove the tiny space below your image.

You can also use `line-height: 0;` on your image container, or set `vertical-align: bottom;` on your img tag. I also see people suggesting that you use `vertical-align: sub;`, but this won't work in IE6 or IE7.

```
td > img { 
  display: block; 
}
```

Comment: Just a note, it's good to use some CSS reset, like [normalize.css](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/blob/master/normalize.css#L409) which contains those table styles.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
```

In CSS, add

```
table {border: none;}
```

Comment: Worth noting that `cellpadding` and `cellspacing` are made obsolete in HTML5. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048913/in-html5-with-respect-to-tables-what-replaces-cellpadding-cellspacing-valign) answer goes over what you should use instead.