# Cellpadding attribute in Table Tag for HTML5

Tags: css, html, html-table

In HTML5, as now the cellpadding is not allowed in the table tag, is there a way I can use the style attribute in table tag only and define the cellpadding.

I don't want to use style css like this:

```
<style>.honey th,.honey td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
}</style>
```

and don't want to add style attribute in each th and td:

```
<td style="padding:10px">January</td><td style="padding:10px">$100</td>
```

Comment: What is the reason that makes you not want to use option 1?

Comment: there are more than 1 tables defined in the page with different paddings. I dont want to insert lot of style tags with different paddings. So was looking if somehow I can define it in the <table> tag.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048913/in-html5-with-respect-to-tables-what-replaces-cellpadding-cellspacing-valign