# How do I reduce all spacing in table cell in html table

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to reduce more spacing and padding in my html table cell?

```css
#table1 td {
  font-size: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table id="table1" border="1">
<tr><td>1</td></tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Also at https://jsfiddle.net/3x2Lgytd/

Comment: Use `line-height: 0.75 or 7` in your `td` in CSS

Answer (score 1):

The space you're referring to is coming from the way the type/text is set, as well as space built into the glyph itself. You can reduce the [line-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) of the text to remove some space above and below a line of text.

```css
td {
  font-size: 200px;
  line-height: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
table 
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

will collapse all borders separating the table columns...

or try

```
<table cellspacing="0" style="border-spacing: 0;">
```

do all **cell-spacing** to 0 and border spacing 0 to achieve same.

```css
#table1 td {
  font-size: 200px;
}

#table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

```html
<table id="table1" border="1" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The use of `cellspacing` is [deprecated in HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement/cellSpacing) and should be avoided. There are [CSS alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6049006/17300).